# LSTM network learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, lstm

I have attempted to program my own LSTM (long short term memory) neural network. I would like to verify that the basic functionality is working. I have implemented a Back propagation through time BPTT algorithm to train a single cell network.

Should a single cell LSTM network be able to learn a simple sequence, or are more than one cells necessary? The network does not seem to be able to learn a simple sequence such as 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1.

I am sending the the sequence 1's and 0's one by one, in order, into the network, and feeding it forward. I record each output for the sequence.

After running the whole sequence through the LSTM cell, I feed the mean error signals back into the cell, saving the weight changes internal to the cell, in a seperate collection, and after running all the errors one by one through and calculating the new weights after each error, I average  the new weights together to get the new weight, for each weight in the cell.

Am i doing something wrong? I would very appreciate any advice.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having only one cell (one hidden unit) is not a good idea even if you are just testing the correctness of your code. You should try 50 even for such simple problem. This paper here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.04069.pdf gives you very clear gradient rules for updating the parameters. Having said that, there is no need to implement your own even if your dataset and/or the problem you are working on is new LSTM. Pick from the existing library (Theano, mxnet, Torch etc...) and modify from there I think is a easier way, given that it's less error prone and it supports gpu computing which is essential for training lstm within a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried 1 hidden unit before, but I am sure 2  or 3 hidden units will work for sequence 0,1,0,1,0,1. It is not necessarily the more the cells, the better the result. Training difficulty also increases with the number of cells.

You said you averaged new weights together to get the new weight. Does that mean you run many training sessions and take the average of the trained   weights?

There are many possibilities your LSTM did not work, even if you implemented it correctly. The weights are not easy to train by simple gradient descent.

Here are my suggestion for weight optimization.

1. Using Momentum method for gradient descent.
2. Add some gaussian noise to your training set to prevent overfitting.
3. using adaptive learning rates for each unit.

Maybe you can take a look at Coursera's course Neural Network offered by Toronto University, and discuss with people there.

Or you can take a look at other examples on GitHub. For instance :

https://github.com/JANNLab/JANNLab/tree/master/examples/de/jannlab/examples

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test an LSTM implementation (after gradient checking) is to try it out on the toy memory problems described in the original LSTM paper itself.

The best one that I often use is the 'Addition Problem':

We give a sequence of tuples of the form (value, mask). Value is a real valued scalar number between 0 and 1. Mask is a binary value - either 0 or 1.

`0.23, 0
0.65, 0
...
0.86, 0
0.13, 1
0.76, 0
...
0.34, 0
0.43, 0
0.12, 1
0.09, 0
..
0.83, 0    ->  0.125`

In the entire sequence of such tuples (usually of length 100), only 2 tuples should have mask as 1, the rest of the tuples should have the mask as 0. The target at the final time step is the a average of the two values for which the mask was 1. The outputs at all other time steps, other than the last one is ignored. The values and the positions of the mask are arbitrarily chosen. Thus, this simple task shows if your implementation can actually remember things over long periods of time.